# Enabling WPS in wpa_supplicant on Debian (Raspbian Jessie)

Tags: debian, raspbian, wpa, wps

I have a wireless network router setup under debian (jessie on a Raspberry Pi) with a fixed IP address, DHCP serving - and it all works fine.

Now I want to enable the router (raspberry) to allow connections setup using a WPS button event.

My (working) wpa_supplicant.conf looks like

```
 country=GB
 ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
 update_config=1
 #CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211=y
 #CONFIG_WPS=y
 #CONFIG_WPS2=y
 #CONFIG_WPS_ER=y
 #uuid=6d035d39-aa07-5517-9e31-efd399828e00
```

The commented outlines are things I have gradually added to try to enable WPS - but basically if I uncomment any/all of them when I try to bring the interface up I get...

pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo ifup wlan0 -v

```
ifup: configuring interface wlan0=wlan0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/hostapd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
ifup: failed to bring up wlan0
```

I am stuck because I have no idea how to debug this further, all I know is the WPA stuff is stopping the interface from coming up!

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or got an idea what I can do to get more info on what is actually failing?

Answer (score 0):

I have failed to find anyone who has successfully done this, despite the documentation suggesting it is possible.

So I would say this can't be done.

FYI: I have moved on and instead of setting up WPS in wpa_supplicant, I am aiming to use
 hostapd to manage the WPS.